# In NodeJs. Why do I get the value from mongodb.ObjectID in the wrong format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

```
var id = new mongodb.ObjectID("545e2fa90293a69004414ae9");
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {});
```

id `value = "T^/©¦AJé"`?
Why?

Help me please!

Comment: ObjectID ist not a String. It's converted to binary format (bytes) internally. Don't worry about it, if it works, it's OK.

Answer (score -1):

To me `mongodb` in your code makes no sense. What you need is `mongoose`, where you bring it in your code with a statement of the form `var mongoose = require('mongoose');`.

In particular, this is the description that mongoose has for the expected id:
[here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_objectid_ObjectId).

My point is, that ObjectIDs are achieved like this:

```
var id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('545e2fa90293a69004414ae9');
console.log('the id is: ' + id);
```

where now you can see the expected string on the console (but as it has been mentioned `ObejectId` is not a string; it is an object as you can easily verify with the `typeof` operator.).

This is why I am not sure what you mean in your code by `mongodb.ObjectId('....');`.